# How can I filter data from my array php?

Tags: php, arrays, object, associative

I am really struggling filtering my data.I know how to access parts of the array but am struggling on how to filter. I know how to do it in SQL SUM & count) but not when it comes to PHP arrays please help.

I need to filter some of my data stored in the variable $res.

I need to see how many times each 'REF' appears & total 'LCL_D_CBM' for each ref all of this where the "TERR" is equal to "TERR1".

```
foreach ($res as $res1){


   if ($res1["TERR"] == "TERR1"){

   //the individual ref 
   //$res1['REF'];  


   // the coutn of how many times each ref appears
   //echo count($res1['REF']);

   //sum
   //echo array_sum($res1['LCL_D_CBM']);    



   }
}
```

need result to be like -

CEA

3

2561

CEF

456

135

```js
var_dump($res); gives me below

array(350) { 
  
[0]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(3) "CEA" ["REF"]=> string(3) "CEA" [1]=> string(5) "1.080" ["LCL_D_CBM"]=> string(5) "1.080" [2]=> string(3) "WF2" ["AREA_CODE"]=> string(3) "WF2" ["TERR"]=> string(5) "TERR1" } 
            
[1]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(3) "CEA" ["REF"]=> string(3) "CEA" [1]=> string(5) "2.000" ["LCL_D_CBM"]=> string(5) "2.000" [2]=> string(4) "HU13" ["AREA_CODE"]=> string(4) "HU13" ["TERR"]=> string(5) "TERR1" } 
            
[2]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(3) "CEF" ["REF"]=> string(3) "CEA" [1]=> string(5) "2.448" ["LCL_D_CBM"]=> string(5) "2.448" [2]=> string(4) "TW16" ["AREA_CODE"]=> string(4) "TW16" ["TERR"]=> string(5) "TERR2" } ..... etc
```

Comment: What is your first tried code to achieve that goal?

Comment: please reformat with line breaks. no one wants to scroll that.

Comment: @bub Please see edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it like this. Not a pretty solution, but should do the work. (I did not test this, so it might contain a spelling error or something):

```
$sum_lcl = 0;
$unique_refs = array();
foreach ($res as $res1){

    if (!array_key_exists($res1['REF'], $unique_refs)) {
        $unique_refs[$res1['REF']] = array();
    }   

    $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]['SUM'] = ( array_key_exists('SUM', $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]) ) ? ( intval( $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]['SUM'] ) + 1 ) : 1;
    $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]['LCL_SUM'] = ( array_key_exists('LCL_SUM', $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]) ) ? ( floatval( $unique_refs[$res1['REF']]['LCL_SUM'] ) + floatval( $res1['LCL_D_CBM'] ) ) : 1;


}


foreach( $unique_refs AS $unique => $data ){
    $title = $unique;
    $sum = $data['SUM'];
    $lcl_sum = $data['LCL_SUM'];
    echo "{$title}<br />{$sum}<br />{$lcl_sum}";
}
```

Comment: Your code sums all the LCL_D_CBM and the count how many times each ref appears doesn't work. please see edited question to see how I would like the results. Thank you

Comment: Mkay. Edited my answer accordingly. From this point though, Id advice you to try yourself to change it if needed to actually learn from it :)

Comment: amazing could you put the icing on the cake and get it to display like in my question so i can get my head round it and learn it. Thank youuu

Comment: Just remove the text I echoed and you would have that. just echo the $unique, $key and $value

Comment: Or add some <br /> tags to make new lines if you like

Comment: the value echos two values (the count and the sum) ? could this be split?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103856/discussion-between-jimmy-the-code-and-ole-haugset).

Comment: Yes. echo $key; echo $value. Or as I said, if you want them on a new line echo $key; echo "<br />"; echo $value; or as I would properly do it: echo "{$key} <br /> {$value}";

Comment: The key echos - SUM and LCL_SUM the value echos the two values. How can i split value so can use as two diffrent vars

Comment: Then just echo the $value variable. echo "{$value} <br />";

Comment: yes that will put them on new lines but I want them as two diff vars

Comment: See the updated answer again. There they are assigned to variables. This is more than what I have time for today, any further questions now and Id advice you to use google or php.net for reference

Comment: Thats it! all sorted :D Thank youuuuuuu